# How to get current language in a play framework action?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I am migrating a Play 2.4 project from Java to Scala.

In Java, I can use `lang().code()` to get the current language.

How can I do the same in Scala?

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaI18N

Comment: I read the documentation of course but I can't find a way to get the current language of a request.

Comment: The doc shows how to get the `acceptLanguages` field out of a `Request`. The `Lang` object in `play.api.i18N` allows you to access the default and available languages.

Comment: Ok thanks. Maybe I should describe my entire problem. Basically, I want to be able to select the language with a button on the client side. I was using changeLang() in Java to modify the selected language. Then in other request, I was retrieving the current language with lang().code(). How is it possible to achieve similar operation in Scala?

Answer (score 3):

You need a `MessagesApi` (doc: [Java](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/play/i18n/MessagesApi.html) and [Scala](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.i18n.Messages)) to call the [`prefered(RequestHeader req)`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/play/i18n/MessagesApi.html#preferred-play.mvc.Http.RequestHeader-) method, which return the current language of the user.

It uses this algorithm to find the best suitable lang:

```
  def preferred(request: RequestHeader) = {
    val maybeLangFromCookie = request.cookies.get(langCookieName).flatMap(c => Lang.get(c.value))
    // match selected lang with play.i18n.langs or return the default one
    val lang = langs.preferred(maybeLangFromCookie.toSeq ++ request.acceptLanguages) 
    Messages(lang, this)
  }
```

I don't use the Java API, but I think you can obtain the messageApi instance with a DI injector:

```
@Inject MessagesApi messagesApi
```